# prove a sequence converges with the following holds

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Suppose that ($a_n$) is an increasing sequence in R, and assume that the following holds: $∃ C ∈R,\;( ∀ n ∈N, \; ∃ m ≥ n,\; (a_m ≤ C)).$ Prove that ($a_n$) converges.

I was thinking the monotone convergence theorem, but I don't know how to prove ($a_n$) is bounded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly right. In fact the sequence must be bounded above by $C$ --- why? Try a proof by contradiction. (Spoilers!):

> Well, suppose there were some $k$ so that $a_k > C$. But by assumption, for every $N$ there exists an $m > N$ such that $a_m \leq C$. In particular, for this $k$, there would exist an $m>k$ such that $a_m \leq C < a_k$, a contradiction to being increasing.

Now do you know anything about bounded, monotone sequences?